# In C#, how do I make a date time picker's value dependant on another date time picker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

For example, I want to have a date time picker for due date that is always two weeks ahead of the selected date for another date time picker. How would I code this, if it is possible?

Comment: @gunr2171 Since when did WPF or Asp.net have a `DateTimePicker`? They have a `DatePicker` and `Calendar` respectively.

Comment: @Khan, not sure about WPF, but you can do ajax with asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty simple using the `ValueChanged` event.

```
//Tie to event to handler
dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add 2 weeks to the value of your second Picker
    dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(14);
}
```